# recurrence relation with min-max

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

While solving a puzzle I got stuck with this recurrence

\begin{align*}  &A(n) = \min_x \left \{ \max \left [ x,  1+A(n-x)
\right ] \right \} \\ &\text{where }A(1) = 1,A(0) = 0 \text{ and } 1 \leq x
\leq n , \text{ x is natural }\\ \end{align*}

Please give some idea how to proceed ?
Thanks !

Comment: Whats is  the nature of $x$  ?   Is it real ?

Comment: No x is natural number

Comment: $A(2)=\min \{ \max\{1, 2\},\max\{2,1+A(0)\} \}$.... so need to know what is $A(0)$

Comment: @MANMAID thanks ! added !

Comment: My python code says `[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]`

Comment: This would give $A(k) = n$ when $2k \in (n(n-1), n(n+1)]$. (when $n \neq 0$)

Comment: Thanks to what @Gribouillis said, it shouldn't be to hard to proceed it by induction.

Comment: @Gribouillis , could you please explain few initial steps ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Got the same outcome with javascript code: var a = [1]; for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {var minVal = Infinity; for (let j=0; j<a.length; j++) {minVal = Math.min(minVal, Math.max(j+1, 1+a[a.length-1-j]));} a.push(minVal); a.push(minVal); }

Comment: The sequence looks like OEIS' [Krushkal-Mccauley function](https://oeis.org/A123578)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Here are a few initial steps:

- Show by induction that $A(n) \le n$
- Show that when $n>1$, $\displaystyle\min_{1\le x\le n} = \min_{1\le x < n}$
- Use this to prove by induction that $A(n)\le A(n+1)$
- Prove that $A(n)\le A(n+1)\le 1 + A(n)$, so that $A(n+1) = A(n) \text{ or } 1+A(n)$